# ASP.Net web application unable to access network mapped folder

Tags: asp.net, mapped-drive

I have an ASP.Net web application hosted on server1.

There is a drive mapped on server1 from another machine server2. Both server1 and server2 are on different domain.

When I take RDP of server1 I can access that mapped drive. But problem is ASP.Net application is unable to access it. I want to write some files in it but unable to do so.

How can I assign proper rights to my ASP.Net application so it can write files in that mapped drive?

Please note:

1. My application is hosted on server1 where drive is mapped
2. Server2 is the machine from where drive is shared on network